# How to get geopoints from Firebase Firestore as List<LatLng> for a Polyline in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents in my firestore database. This is one of the documents:
[image]

In my app I want to show Polylines on the Google Map based on the points in the document. The Polyline requires points as a List of Latitudes und Longitudes like this:

```
points: <LatLng>[
  LatLng(0, 0),
  LatLng(1, 1),
],
```

However if I get the points from firestore it receives the points as a `List<dynamic>` and not a `List<LatLng>`.

This is the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<LatLng>'
```

My question is: How can I get the points from my Firestore database as a `List<LatLng>` or how can I write LatLngs in the database so I can build Polylines to the Map no matter how much points the list in the database has.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `List<dynamic>` into `List<LatLng>` using [map](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-collection/ListMixin/map.html) method.

Assuming **points** array only consists of GeoPoint objects:

```
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
await db.collection("your-collection-name").get().then((event) {
  for (var doc in event.docs) {
    final docData = doc.data();
    List<dynamic> points = docData['points'];
    final latlngPoints = points.map((e) => LatLng(e.latitude, e.longitude));
  }
});
```